# Why can I mark a method from an interface that inherits another interface as private?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, private

Afaik, in C#, any implemented method from an interface must be public.

```
interface A { void DoA(); }
class B : A { public void DoA() {} }
```

But if you inherit an interface that inherits from another interface, then you can mark the base interface method as private.

```
interface A1 { void DoA1(); }
interface A2 : A1 { void DoA2(); }
class B : A2
{
    public void DoA2() { } // Still need to be marked as public
    void A1.DoA1() { } // Can be marked as private
    // or I can do this: public void DoA1() { }
}
```

This first comes to my attention when I see a class `class MyClass : IEnumerable<SomeType>` do exactly this.

```
public IEnumerator<MyType> GetEnumerator() { ... }
private IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { ... }
```

Why is this allowed? Why can I pass an instance of `B` to a method that takes an `A1` even though `DoA1` is private? I couldn't find any documentation about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`void A1.DoA1() { }` does not mark method as private, it is an [explicit interface implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation):

> An explicit interface implementation doesn't have an access modifier since it isn't accessible as a member of the type it's defined in. Instead, it's only accessible when called through an instance of the interface. If you specify an access modifier for an explicit interface implementation, you get compiler error CS0106.

i.e. `private IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { ... }` will not even compile.

> Why is this allowed? Why can I pass an instance of B to a method that takes an A1 even though DoA1 is private?

As described earlier `DoA1` is not private and can't be, because interface is a contract and if class implements an interface it should satisfy the contract, otherwise the compilation should fail (so type safety is preserved).

One of the usages for explicit interface implementation is exactly the `IEnumerable<T>` case - `IEnumerable<T>` extends `IEnumerable` and both define member with the same signature (return type is not part of the signature) - `GetEnumerator` so to be able to satisfy both contracts one is implemented explicitly.

Another usage (which can be considered valid for `IEnumerable<T>` too) is interface members "hiding" - when there are methods that developer does not want to be accessed via the implementation type and/or in case of interface inheritance when descendant interface exposes "preferable" version of the method (for example in `IGenericInterface<T> : INonGenericInterface` scenarios like with `IEnumerable`).

> But if you inherit an interface that inherits from another interface, then you can mark the base interface method as private.

No interface inheritance is actually needed, interface can be partially (or fully) explicitly implemented:

```cs
interface A1 { void DoA1(); void DoA2();}
class B : A1
{
    public void DoA2() { } 
    void A1.DoA1() { } 
}
```

Comment: So is `DoA1` marked as public? If I use reflection on class B with BindingFlags.Public (or NonPublic) what will happen?

Comment: @longtran2904 try it yourself, but my guess would be that it is `NonPublic` when accessed via reflection on class type info.

Answer (score 1):

Also worth mentioning that explicit interface implementations lets you tailor/declutter your class APIs to more intuitive member names  without loosing polyphormism when leveraging the interface typed reference. Explained better in an example:

```
interface IAnimal
{
    string MakeSound();
}

class Dog : IAnimal
{
    string IAnimal.MakeSound() => Bark();
    public string Bark() => "Woof!";
}

class Cat : IAnimal
{
    string IAnimal.MakeSound() => Meow();
    public string Meow() => "Meow!";
}

//etc.
```

This is probably a very secondary advantage but useful in some scenarios.